# How can I adjust the heatmap to show everything?

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

My heatmap is cutting the element labels off and I don't want them to be displayed on the bottom at all.  How can I adjust this so it fits everything on it?  Also the key is taking up too much space, but when I make it less than 1 the key and the title disappears.  [image]

```
heatmap.2( x=correlation_mat,
           dendrogram="column",
           keysize = 1,
           key.title = NA,
           key.ylab = NA,
           density.info = "none",
           trace = "none",
           Colv = "Rowv",
           scale = "none",
           col = rev(colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(10, "RdBu"))(256)),
           main = "Correlations of Thickness")
```

You will need the gplots and RColorBrewer libraries for this.

Comment: We will also need your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enlarge the margins with an additional `margins` argument with two values.

The following example uses random data:

```
library("gplots")
library("RColorBrewer")

## sample data
x <- matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow=10)

## random lables
dimnames(x) <- list(
  replicate(10, paste(sample(letters, 10, replace=TRUE), collapse="")),
  replicate(100, paste(sample(letters, 10, replace=TRUE), collapse=""))
)

correlation_mat <- cor(x)

heatmap.2(x=correlation_mat,
          dendrogram="column",
          keysize = 1,
          key.title = NA,
          key.ylab = NA,
          density.info = "none",
          trace = "none",
          Colv = "Rowv",
          scale = "none",
          col = rev(colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(10, "RdBu"))(256)),
          main = "Correlations of Thickness",
          margins = c(8, 8))
```

To remove the bottom labels completely `margins = c(1, 8)`worked for me.